# Stop Running @selector action

Tags: objective-c, action, selector

I am running:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkTheUsersText) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

and as you can see it runs every 0.01 second! Is there a way to cancel that after it is finished. For example if the user dismisses the keyboard stop running (checkTheUsersText)? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some more background on what method this line is in? afterDelay: is setting up a .01 second delay before sending your message.  Also what is the goal you are trying to achieve with this code? We might be able to give you a nudge in a better direction if you can give us more to work with.

Comment: buddy it runs only once

Comment: haha yeah I forgot to mention I ran the (checkTheUsersText) after 0.01 then (checkTheUsersText2) after 0.01 which then leads back to (checkTheUsersText)! So it like a small little loop.

Comment: You should **never** poll in a tight loop like this.  It is not necessary and it wastes battery life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This wont run every 0.01 seconds, it will be called only once after a delay of 0.01 secs from the current time
- Even if it gets called only once, you can again cancel the request using

  ```
  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                       selector:@selector(checkTheUsersText)
                                         object:nil];
  ```

For more details please refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a)